# How to run Coded UI Tests against the Windows Azure SDK v1.4

Tags: azure, coded-ui-tests

I have an MVC3 web application that has grown to the point I want to start automating some of the functional testing.  So, I've been trying to add a Coded UI Test to the same project that I put unit tests into.  Nothing but frustration.

I have been able to record a simple series of steps: logging into the application.

I was able to generate the code and I can see the generated code in a file named UIMap.Designer.cs.  An instance of this class is instantiated and the test method is called in a file I named LoginTest.cs.

When I try to right-click on the [TestMethod] in LoginTest.cs and choose Run Test, I was initially getting the following error:

> Unable to load the test container 'C:...\WebRole.Tests.dll' or one of its dependencies. Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So, I flipped the following References from Copy Local = false to true:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework

Now, when I run the test, I get the following output:

> Testing started:
>
> Total tests: 1, filtered: 1
>
> No tests found.
>
> Duration : 94.9989452249951

A browser instance isn't started.  Neither the Azure Compute nor the Azure Storage emulators are started.  The application isn't packaged and deployed.  In short, none of the things that happen when I run the application seem to happen.  So, I'm puzzled about how the UI Test could run at all, since the Azure emulator environment isn't running.

To work around this, I tried opening two instances of VS2010.  In the first, I ran the application as usual to get the Azure emulators running and the application deployed.  In the second, I ran the CodedUITest method.  Same results.

Now, I'm stuck.  Is anybody else able to run a Coded UI Test against the Azure emulators provided with Azure SDK v1.4?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way too late for the OP, but may help someone else with a similar issue (that was me a couple of hours ago).

Caveat: I'm a complete newbie with CodedUI, so this may not be the *right* way to do this. But at least it got me started.

I've got a similar situation: Azure 1.4, ASP.NET MVC (2 in my case) web app. I want to start a suite of UI tests that I can run in my desktop development environment (VS2010 Premium).

Here are the steps that got me started:
1. Record a bit of a CodedUI test - just so you'll have something to see running to prove that you are able to do this. (I followed the first few steps from this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286608.aspx).

Open the browser before you start recording and record everything you need to do to start your web app.

1. Add initialization code to the test to start the browser:
   In your Coded UI test class, add a method with a [TestInitialize] attribute:

> ```
>     [TestInitialize]
>     public void LaunchBroswer()
>     {
>         BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri("https://127.0.0.2/Logon"));
>     }
> ```

Your URI may, of course, vary. This was the bit of magic I had to infer from some other posts. Having TestInitialize in a collapsed code region didn't help.

1. To run the tests, start the Azure emulators: Ctrl+F5 (which will start the web app in a browser, but not running the test.
2. You can now run the test from the same instance of VS that you started the emulators from.

Answer (score -1):

the pain you are experiencing is not only related to Azure, but to coded UI test as a whole IMHO. for MVC (and asp.net) there are a couple of tools that could ease the pain (and you'll not need the coded ui suite).

did you try [SpecFlow](http://specflow.org/) and [WatiN](http://watin.org)? there is even a package you can use from Nuget that is build as part of the [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) library.

hope it will help you to test the UI.

checkout channel9 for some instructions like: [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Brandom-Satrom-BDD-in-ASPNET-MVC-using-SpecFlow-WatiN-and-WatiN-Test-Helpers)